# Clam Antivirus auto scan on certain time on Linux?

Tags: linux, security, clamav

I required to know from experts, how can we run Clam Antivirus (https://www.clamav.net/) and auto scan at a certain time on a Linux machine.
I don't know how this will be done, I need to create a crontab, or is there any configuration available with Clam Antivirus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a crontab. Personal preference is to write a custom script to be called by cron and execute it so as to write a log file also in the process.

```
#! /bin/bash
scantime=$(date -u +%H) 
#writes hour of scan, assuming to be run every 6 hours
fileout="$HOME/clamav-$(date -u +'%Hh-%d-%Y').log"

path="/var $HOME/Downloads"

for i in $path; do
    echo "Starting hourly scan of $i
    clamscan -r --bell -i $i >> $fileout
    wait
done
```

and then add `0 0 0/6 1/1 * ? * /path/to/script` to `crontab -e`. This will run the script every 6 hours.

Comment: What is `clamscan`? is it the real name of ClamAV process? I have not installed ClamAV, can you just give me quick shot on steps assisting to install on RHEL or Ubuntu.

Comment: Please read the [official documentation](https://www.clamav.net/documents/installing-clamav) for help with installation. `Clamscan` is a command line utility that performs a scan.

Comment: this script should be saved like `scanner.sh` or just `scanner`? Or it doesn't matter.

Comment: Does not matter